# JainSip: UPDATE request not seen after sending no response

Tags: jain-sip

The UPDATE request for session refresh is not seen on my server user interface. The client sends a UPDATE request, the server is set in no response mode. The UPDATE request is re transmitted,but in the server user interface it is not seen(processrequest is not called). In the log I see [Request Consumed -- next consumable Request Seqno = 2]. What does this indicate?

Comment: The CSeq header must increase with each new request within the dialog. The UPDATE may have wrong CSeq. Can you post the requests and the logs?

Comment: Thanks Vladmir Ralev for responding. But this request is not a new request, the client re-transmits the same request till timer F expires.My understanding is that the Cseq number will not increase, the re-transmitted request is not displayed in the server user interface. I am able to see the request in wireshark.

Comment: OK. Then everything you see is normal. The message in the log simply indicates that the request is received and the internal counter moved on to expect CSeq>=2. The retransmissions should eventually stop and the SIP stack will recover by forgetting about this transaction when it times out. That's the expected behaviour here.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir Ralev. Is there any way I can display that Request in my user interface, we need this for some testing purpose. Any flags or some other work around. Please let me know there is anything which we can do.

Comment: Check the logging options here https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/javadoc/gov/nist/javax/sip/SipStackImpl.html in the higher trace levels the messages are printed, but it also depends on the code paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladimir Ralev. Will surely look into that option.